# Mobile phones supporting Java Android?

Tags: java, android, nokia

What are mobile phones supporting Java Android?

Is there any Nokia phone supporting this technology?

What should the mobile contain (a framework, a plugin.. etc) if we want to deploy a Java Android Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is a fairly comprehensive [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) comparing devices running Android, including forthcoming devices.
2. Nokia seems to have no interest using Android platform for its devices.
3. If the device is a certified Android platform, there is nothing one needs to add for deployment.

Answer (score 7):

Android can be deployed to many devices with custom builds of the OS; anyone can build Android . It is not limited to particular handset makers and you might want to consult the makers for official lists of deployed devices.

There is nothing the device needs to contain (other then an appropriate targeted version of Andrdoid) to deploy an application.

One important note is that the application IS NOT run in the JVM, the code is only written in Java and then converted to Dalvik bytecode when compiling (Android runs on the Dalvik Virtual Machine). Since the code is written in Java though you can make extensive use of existing libraries and use them in your applications.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Indeed! I think this  is an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

I think most phones that run Android should support Android applications.  <strike>However, IMHO one would be hard pressed to compile a list of those phone.But rest assured, it's a lot.</strike>    [Someone DID make a list!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices)  And yep, it's a lot.

Some quick Googling reveal that Nokia seems to not like Android so I would assume there is not a Nokia phone with Android.

Framework: Eclipse Galileo with the ADT plugin

My advice:

read this site inside and out! http://developer.android.com/index.html

It answers all your questions.